# Any symplectic manifold is a Poisson manifold.

Tags: differential-forms, vector-fields, symplectic-geometry, quantum-groups, poisson-geometry

> Let $M$ be a symplectic manifold with a non-degenerate closed $2$-form $\omega.$ Then for any $f \in C^{\infty} (M)$ and for any vector field $u \in \mathfrak {X} (M)$ there exists a vector field $V_{f} \in \mathfrak {X} (M)$ such that $df (u) = \omega (u, V_{f}).$

I know that any differential $2$-form on $M$ can be thought of as a $C^{\infty} (M)$-bilinear, skew-symmetric map from $\mathfrak {X} (M) \times \mathfrak {X} (M) \longrightarrow C^{\infty} (M).$ So the $1$-form $\omega (u, \cdot) : \mathfrak {X} (M) \longrightarrow C^{\infty} (M)$ is a $C^{\infty} (M)$-linear map for any vector field $u \in \mathfrak {X} (M).$ Now how do I show that for any $f \in C^{\infty} (M)$ there exists a vector field $V_{f} \in \mathfrak {X} (M)$ such that $df (u) = \omega (u, V_{f})$ or in other words the smooth function $df (u)$ is actually in the image of the $1$-form $\omega (u, \cdot)\ $? The above exercise would help us concluding that any symplectic manifold is a Poisson manifold.

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

**Source** $:$ Lecture Notes on CQG by Pavel Etingof.

Comment: Hint: The nondegeneracy of $\omega$ means that the map $X\mapsto \omega(X,\cdot)$ is an isomorphism $\mathfrak{X}(M)\to \Omega^1(M)$.

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter$:$ Isomorphism as what? As $C^{\infty} (M)$-modules because the map is clearly seen to be $C^{\infty} (M)$-linear? Non-degeneracy of $\omega$ would clearly imply the map $X \mapsto \omega (X, \cdot)$ is injective. But why is it surjective?

Comment: Assuming you are working in the finite dimensional case, then yes as $C^\infty(M)$ modules. If $M$ is finite dimensional, $\dim T_pM=\dim T_p^*M$ for each $p\in M$. Nondegeneracy means the map $T_pM\to T_p^*M$ is injective and hence an isomorphism. This means that this map induces a vector bundle isomorphism $TM\to T^*M$ and hence an isomorphism of sections as $C^\infty(M)$ modules $\Gamma(TM, M)\to \Gamma(T^*M,M)$.

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter$:$ I use slightly different definition of non-degeneracy. According to my definition the $2$-form $\omega$ is non-degenerate if $\omega (X,Y) = 0$ for all $X \implies Y = 0$ and $\omega (X,Y) = 0$ for all $Y \implies X = 0.$ Are these two definitions equivalent?

Comment: Given that the map $X \mapsto \omega (X, \cdot)$ is an isomorphism of $C^{\infty} (M)$-modules the rest part is very easy. For a given $f \in C^{\infty} (M)$ choose $V_{f} \in \mathfrak {X} (M)$ such that $\omega (-V_{f} , \cdot ) = df$ and then by using bilinearity and skew-symmetry of $\omega$ it follows that $\omega (\cdot, V_{f}) = df.$ Hence for any $u \in \mathfrak {X} (M)$ it follows that $\omega (u, V_{f}) = df (u).$ Done!

Comment: Actually what we need is the surjectivity of the above map.

Comment: The statement I gave about nondegeneracy follows from the definition you gave (which is the standard one) as follows: To show that the map $X\mapsto \omega(X, \cdot)$ is an injective map $\phi:T_pM\to T^*_pM$ it suffices to show that it has trivial kernel. Assume that $X\in\ker \phi$ this means that $\phi(X)=0$ and hence $\phi(X)(Y)=0$ for all $Y\in T_pM$. Because $\phi(X)(Y)=\omega(X,Y)$, $X=0$.

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter$:$ Injectivity is not an issue. I want to show surjectivity using my definition of non-degeneracy.

Comment: Any injective map between finite dimensional vector spaces of the same dimension is an isomorphism (and hence surjective) as I said in my second comment.

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter$:$ Isn't the map you initially defined is a map from $\mathfrak {X} (M) \longrightarrow \Omega^{1} (M)\ $?

Comment: Comments are not the correct place for extended discussion, if you would like we can continue in the chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140975/discussion-between-anil-bagchi-and-j-v-gaiter

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter$:$ chat doesn't allow us to edit in latex.